# Kill an instance of a particular process running more than an hour

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to kill an ftpscrpt (IPSwitch file transfer) process running for more than an hour.  The catch is that I have some exceptions. 
 I have this process running for multiple file transfers in which a few takes more than an hour, genuinely.  
I was trying to work that out with the below command but couldn't restrict it to kill for a specific instance.

Powershell
`Get-Process ftpscrpt | Where StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60) | Stop-Process -Force`

Attaching a screenshot which might give you more details on those processes.
[image]

I want to kill just the first one based on the .scp file's name.  Let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the command line of a process with the `Get-Process` cmdlet afaik. But you can get it by querying WMI:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'ftpscrpt.exe'" | Where-Object {(($_.CreationDate -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60)) -and ($_.CommandLine -like "*youNameIt.scp*"))} | ForEach-Object {Stop-Process -Id $_.ProcessId}
```